# Mesh Modifier System in the Unity Game Engine using C#

Tags: c#, performance, unity3d, entity-component-system

The system is meant to replicate the deformers and modifiers commonly used in 3D modeling programs like 3DS Max, Maya, Blender and Cinema 4D. I made a [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/5h1odl/mesh_modifiers_is_now_on_github/) on Reddit, explaining the features and limitations. If you (understandably) don't want to look through [all the code](https://github.com/keenanwoodall/MeshModifiers), I'll list the important base classes.

I'm looking for feedback and suggestions on my code. I think feedback related to optimization would help me the most.

MeshModifiers/Code/Scripts/MeshModifiers/**ModifierObject**.cs
MeshModifiers/Code/Scripts/MeshModifiers/BaseClasses/**MeshModifierBase**.cs

All the other classes are utility, or inherit from **MeshModifierBase**.

**ModifierObject**.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MeshModifiers
{
    [RequireComponent (typeof (MeshFilter))]
    public class ModifierObject : MonoBehaviour
    {
        #region Public Properties

        [Header ("General")]

        public bool autoUpdate = true;

        [Range (0f, 1f)]
        public float modifierStrength = 1f;


        [Header ("Surface")]

        [Tooltip (MeshModifierConstants.NORMALS_QUALITY_TOOLTIP)]
        public NormalsQuality normalQuality = NormalsQuality.LowQuality;

        [Range (0f, 180f), Tooltip (MeshModifierConstants.SMOOTHING_ANGLE_TOOLTIP)]
        public float smoothingAngle = 60f;


        [Header ("Performance")]

        [System.NonSerialized, Tooltip (MeshModifierConstants.UPDATE_WHEN_HIDDEN_TOOLTIP)]
        public bool updateWhenHidden = false;

        [Range (1, MeshModifierConstants.MAX_MOD_FRAMES), Tooltip (MeshModifierConstants.MODIFY_FRAMES_TOOLTIP)]
        public int modifyFrames = 1;



        [System.NonSerialized]
        public List<MeshModifierBase> modifiers = new List<MeshModifierBase> ();

        [System.NonSerialized]
        public bool refreshModifiersEveryFrame = true;

        /// <summary>
        /// Updated based on Unity's OnWillRenderObject and OnBecameVisible.
        /// </summary>
        public bool isVisible { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// The index that corresponds the current chunk of vertices being modified.
        /// </summary>
        public int currentModifiedChunkIndex { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Local to the modifier object. Used to sync modifications that occur over multiple frames and require a time value.
        /// </summary>
        public float Time { get; private set; }

        #endregion



        #region Backed Properties

        private MeshFilter filter;
        public MeshFilter Filter
        {
            get
            {
                if (filter == null)
                    filter = GetComponent<MeshFilter> ();
                return filter;
            }
            set { filter = value; }
        }

        private Mesh mesh;
        public Mesh Mesh
        {
            get
            {
                if (mesh == null)
                    mesh = filter.mesh;
                return mesh;
            }
            set { mesh = value; }
        }

        #endregion



        #region Private Properties

        private Vector3[] baseVertices;
        private Vector3[] modifiedVertices;
        private Vector3[] baseNormals;
        private Vector3[] modifiedNormals;

        #endregion



        #region Unity Methods

        void Awake ()
        {
            Filter = GetComponent<MeshFilter> ();

            ChangeMesh (Filter.mesh);
        }

        void Start ()
        {
            RefreshModifiers ();
            StartCoroutine (AutoApplyModifiers ());
        }

        void OnWillRenderObject ()
        {
            isVisible = true;
        }

        void OnBecameInvisible ()
        {
            isVisible = false;
        }

        #endregion



        #region Main Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Modifies the whole mesh, as one chunk.
        /// [HINT]: This method only changes the internal data, call ApplyModifications for the mesh data to reflect the internal data.
        /// </summary>
        public void ModifyAll (bool invokePreMods = true, bool invokePostMods = false)
        {
            int[] useableModifiers = GetUseableModifiers ();

            if (invokePreMods)
                InvokePreMods (useableModifiers);

            ModifyChunk (0, baseVertices.Length, useableModifiers);

            if (invokePostMods)
                InvokePostMods (useableModifiers);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Modifies the whole mesh, as one chunk.
        /// [HINT]: This method only changes the internal data, call ApplyModifications for the mesh data to reflect the internal data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="modifierIndexes">Represent indexes of modifiers in the 'modifiers' list that will be applied to the mesh.</param>
        public void ModifyAll (int[] modifierIndexes, bool invokePreMods = true, bool invokePostMods = false)
        {
            if (invokePreMods)
                InvokePreMods (modifierIndexes);

            ModifyChunk (0, baseVertices.Length, modifierIndexes);

            if (invokePostMods)
                InvokePostMods (modifierIndexes);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Modifies chunk of the mesh. If modifiersIndexes is null, all useable modifiers will be applied.
        /// [HINT]: This method only changes the internal data, call ApplyModifications for the mesh data to reflect the internal data.
        /// [HINT]: Any modifiers that inherit the PreMod or PostMod method won't work without InvokePreMods and/or InvokePostMods being called. This allows you to call those methods once (before a set of chunks are processed), rather than everytime you change a chunk.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="startIndex"></param>
        /// <param name="stopIndex"></param>
        /// <param name="modifierIndexes">Represent indexes of modifiers in the 'modifiers' list that will be applied to the chunk.</param>
        public void ModifyChunk (int startIndex, int stopIndex, int[] modifierIndexes = null)
        {
            // If modifierIndexes are not supplied, use all useabled modifiers.
            if (modifierIndexes == null)
                modifierIndexes = GetUseableModifiers ();

            // For each vertex in this chunk...
            for (int currentVert = startIndex; currentVert < stopIndex; currentVert++)
            {
                // For each modifier...
                for (int currentMod = 0; currentMod < modifierIndexes.Length; currentMod++)
                    modifiedVertices[currentVert] = modifiers[modifierIndexes[currentMod]].ModifyOffset (modifiedVertices[currentVert], modifiedNormals[currentVert]);

                PostModPointOperation (currentVert);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Call this after calling ModifyAll or ModifyChunk for the changes to be applied the the actual mesh.
        /// </summary>
        public void ApplyModifications ()
        {
            // Update the mesh's vertices to reflect the modified vertices.
            Mesh.SetVertices (modifiedVertices.ToList ());

            // Update the normals.
            RefreshSurface (normalQuality);

            Mesh.RecalculateBounds ();

            // Reset the modded vertices to their base state so next frames modifications are based on the original vertices.
            ResetVerticesAndNormals ();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// A safe way to change the modified mesh.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="newMesh"></param>
        public void ChangeMesh (Mesh newMesh)
        {
            Filter.mesh = newMesh;
            Mesh = Filter.mesh;
            Mesh.MarkDynamic ();

            baseVertices = (Vector3[])Filter.sharedMesh.vertices.Clone ();
            baseNormals = (Vector3[])Filter.sharedMesh.normals.Clone ();
            ResetVerticesAndNormals ();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Recalculates normals.
        /// </summary>
        public void RefreshSurface (NormalsQuality normalsQuality)
        {
            if (normalsQuality == NormalsQuality.None)
                return;

            switch (normalsQuality)
            {
                case NormalsQuality.LowQuality:
                    Mesh.RecalculateNormals ();
                    break;
                case NormalsQuality.HighQuality:
                    Mesh.RecalculateNormals (smoothingAngle);
                    break;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Updates the list of modifiers, including their order of execution.
        /// </summary>
        public void RefreshModifiers ()
        {
            modifiers = GetComponents<MeshModifierBase> ().ToList ();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Reverts any changes made to the vertices and their normals, and updates the base vertices and normals in case custom code has changed the mesh.
        /// </summary>
        private void ResetVerticesAndNormals ()
        {
            modifiedVertices = (Vector3[])baseVertices.Clone ();
            modifiedNormals = (Vector3[])baseNormals.Clone ();
        }

        #endregion



        #region Utility Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the number of vertices and handles missing references
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int GetVertCount ()
        {
            return (Filter.sharedMesh) ? Filter.sharedMesh.vertexCount : 0;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the position of a vertex and handles missing references.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="index"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Vector3 GetVertPosition (int index)
        {
            return (Filter.sharedMesh) ? transform.rotation * Filter.sharedMesh.vertices[index] : Vector3.zero;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the world position of a vertex at the given index and handles missing references.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="index"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Vector3 GetVertWorldPosition (int index)
        {
            return transform.position + GetVertPosition (index);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the number of vertices being modified each frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int GetModifiedVertsPerFrame ()
        {
            return GetVertCount () / modifyFrames;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the number of vertices being modified per second.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int GetModifiedVertsPerSecond ()
        {
            return (int)(60f * (GetModifiedVertsPerFrame () * UnityEngine.Time.deltaTime));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the current state of the modified vertices.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Vector3[] GetCurrentVerts ()
        {
            return modifiedVertices.Clone () as Vector3[];
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an array of the vertices' world positions.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Vector3[] GetCurrentWorldVerts ()
        {
            Vector3[] worldVerts = GetCurrentVerts ();

            for (int i = 0; i < worldVerts.Length; i++)
                worldVerts[i] = (Mathx.Vectorx.Multiply (transform.rotation * worldVerts[i], transform.localScale)) + transform.position;

            return worldVerts;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an array of modifiers that wants to be used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public int[] GetUseableModifiers ()
        {
            RefreshModifiers ();
            List<int> modIndexes = new List<int> ();

            for (int i = 0; i < modifiers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (modifiers[i] == null)
                {
                    modifiers.RemoveAt (i);
                    i--;
                    continue;
                }
                if (modifiers[i].update)
                    modIndexes.Add (i);
            }

            return modIndexes.ToArray ();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the bounds of the original mesh.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Bounds GetBounds ()
        {
            return new Bounds (Filter.mesh.bounds.center, Filter.mesh.bounds.size);
        }

        #endregion



        #region Internal Utility Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Should this object perform modifications to the mesh?
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private bool CanModify ()
        {
            return (isVisible || updateWhenHidden) && autoUpdate;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finds the number of vertices that can't be grouped in the chunks.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="vertCount"></param>
        /// <param name="chunkSize"></param>
        /// <param name="chunkAmount"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private int CalcVertRemainder (int vertCount, int chunkSize, int chunkAmount)
        {
            return vertCount - (chunkSize * chunkAmount);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invokes the PreMod methods on all of the modifiers.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="modIndexes"></param>
        private void InvokePreMods (int[] modIndexes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < modIndexes.Length; i++)
                modifiers[modIndexes[i]].PreMod ();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invokes the PostMod methods on all of the modifiers.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="modIndexes"></param>
        private void InvokePostMods (int[] modIndexes)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < modIndexes.Length; i++)
                modifiers[modIndexes[i]].PostMod ();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is where any final modifications will be performed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="currentVertex"></param>
        private void PostModPointOperation (int currentVertex)
        {
            if (!Mathf.Approximately (modifierStrength, 1f))
                modifiedVertices[currentVertex] = Vector3.Lerp (baseVertices[currentVertex], modifiedVertices[currentVertex], modifierStrength);
        }

        #endregion



        #region Coroutines

        /// <summary>
        /// Does ApplyModifiers over x frames to lessen performance impact.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private IEnumerator AutoApplyModifiers ()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (CanModify ())
                {
                    // The current chunk index starts at zero.
                    currentModifiedChunkIndex = 0;

                    // Store the number of splits in a local variable so that if modifyFrames is changed before the modifications are complete, nothing will get messed up.
                    int chunks = modifyFrames;
                    // Find the approximate number of vertices in a single split.
                    int chunkSize = Mesh.vertexCount / chunks;

                    // Increment time based on how much approximate time will have passed when the mods are done.
                    Time += UnityEngine.Time.deltaTime * chunks;

                    InvokePreMods (GetUseableModifiers ());

                    // For each chunk...
                    for (int currentChunkIndex = 0; currentChunkIndex < chunks; currentChunkIndex++)
                    {
                        if (refreshModifiersEveryFrame)
                            RefreshModifiers ();

                        ModifyChunk (chunkSize * currentChunkIndex, chunkSize * (currentChunkIndex + 1) + ((currentChunkIndex + 1 == chunks) ? CalcVertRemainder (GetVertCount (), chunkSize, chunks) : 0), GetUseableModifiers ());

                        // The current chunk's modifications are finished so the next chunk will start being processed.
                        currentModifiedChunkIndex++;

                        // Wait a frame.
                        yield return null;
                    }

                    // Update the mesh to reflect the new modifications.
                    ApplyModifications ();

                    InvokePostMods (GetUseableModifiers ());
                }
                else
                    yield return null;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

**MeshModifierBase**

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace MeshModifiers
{
    [RequireComponent (typeof (ModifierObject))]
    public abstract class MeshModifierBase : MonoBehaviour
    {
        #region Public Properties

        public bool update = true;

        #endregion



        #region Private Properties

        protected ModifierObject modObject;
        private Mesh mesh;

        #endregion



        #region Unity Methods

        void Awake ()
        {
            modObject = GetComponent<ModifierObject> ();
        }

        #endregion



        #region Main Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Performs any calculations that shouldn't be executed for each vertice.
        /// An example would be updating the modifiers reference to the meshes new bounds.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void PreMod () { }
        /// <summary>
        /// Performs any calculations that shouldn't be executed for each vertice, after the modification is complete.
        /// An example would be updating the modifiers reference to the meshes new bounds.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void PostMod () { }

        public Vector3 ModifyOffset (Vector3 position, Vector3 normal)
        {
            if (update)
                return _ModifyOffset (position, normal);
            else
                return position;
        }

        protected abstract Vector3 _ModifyOffset (Vector3 basePosition, Vector3 baseNormal);

        public virtual void DrawEditorGUI ()
        {
            update = GUILayout.Toggle (update, "Update");
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! `I'm looking for feedback and suggestions on my code` is a bit vague - anything in particular you're hoping to get feedback on? Performance, code style/conventions, design, etc.?

Comment: @avojak Good point, sorry! I'm looking for advice on performance. To put it simply, are there more efficient ways to loop through a bunch of vectors and apply modifications? Check out my [post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/5h1odl/mesh_modifiers_is_now_on_github/) if you wanna see videos of it in-action.